# Reading data from a binary file in Python

Tags: python, binary

I have a python code that I don't really understand since I am super new to python that reads data from a binary file and spits out a CSV file.

The code is in this site I can't post it on here because it is huge.
https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/blob/master/Tools/sdlog2/sdlog2_dump.py

Now I know you must have the key to a binary file to be able to parse it and use its data. What I don't understand is how that code that I linked above does this or where the key in the code is. I have tried reading the code and breaking it down, but due to my limited knowledge I have no idea where to go from here.

I am trying to extract the key so that I can write my own code using the key to parse the data in the binary file.

Comment: What makes you think you need a 'key'? Scanning through the code doesn't seem to reveal that the file it processes is encrypted in any way. It just reads the binary format and extracts the fields from it using the struct module.  Anyway what stops you from using that code you linked to do your own data processing on the csv file that it produces?

Comment: @IrmendeJong Well, binary files are just zeros and ones correct? how would you know what is your start and stop bit to read the data? Also, I know I can use the CSV file, but I am trying to see if it is possible to do it this way as a learning experience in case I need to do something similar where I don't have a nice code that will do the CSV conversion for me.

Comment: Read up on the struct module and see in the source you linked, how it is being used to parse the binary data (bytes) into managable separate fields.   For example: it takes 4 bytes, interprets those as an integer, and stores that in a colum. The next 8 bytes are turned into a floating point number and stored in the next column. The following 20 bytes are a string etc etc.    The "key" you mention is probably the binary file format specification. I googled a bit but can't find something relevant right now so you probably have to go by the struct format from the python source

Comment: @IrmendeJong Could you point out where in the code you are reading the 4 bytes and 8 bytes part?

Comment: ...it was just an example